# Scala and Mongodb : how to execute dbdump in scala?

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework

how to execute dbdump in scala? so far this is all I have but not working :

```
val mongoConn = MongoConnection( "db" )
mongoConn.mongoDump("path")
mongoConn.underlying.close()
```

Looking forward for the answer please.

Comment: Have you done any research? Seen the documentation for mongo driver for scala?

Comment: hi matejkramny, yes but im having hard time of searching it in implementing to scala

Comment: i am not familiar with Scala, but see http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/scala/ for list of drivers, and the first one (http://reactivemongo.org) seems to have lots of examples.. Hope this helps!